# PyMeshLab - Target Length abs Filter script - Isotropic Explicit Remeshing

Tags: pymeshlab

I would like to remesh my model using filter called "Remeshing: Isotropic Explicit Remeshing". In that filter, I'd like to adjust the target length. There are two types of target length, abs and %. But in the filter script available in PyMeshLab, there is only filter script for target length in terms of %. I don't want to adjust the percentage as I want to apply the same script for different size of models, where abs target length (in world unit format) will make more similar edge length rather than % form.

Is there anyway I can write the script for target length in abs form?

Answer (score 1):

I think that documentation for [remeshing_isotropic_explicit_remeshing](https://pymeshlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filter_list.html#remeshing_isotropic_explicit_remeshing) is not very clear. I'm supposing you are using current version of pymeshlab (21.10)

if you pass a float value as parameter, it should be interpreted as an absolute value. You can force this behavior using arguments of type `pymeshlab.AbsoluteValue(x)`. If you need to interpreter arguments as percentage value, use `pymeshlab.Percentage(x)`.
You can find an example [here](https://pymeshlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/apply_filter_parameters_percentage.html)

```py
import pymeshlab

ms = pymeshlab.MeshSet()
ms.load_new_mesh('bunny10k.ply')

#Apply absolute value 3 as argument
ms.remeshing_isotropic_explicit_remeshing(targetlen = pymeshlab.AbsoluteValue(3))
ms.save_current_mesh('output1.ply')

ms.load_new_mesh('bunny10k.ply')
#Apply percentage 3% as argument
ms.remeshing_isotropic_explicit_remeshing(targetlen = pymeshlab.Percentage(3))
ms.save_current_mesh('output2.ply')
```